# Handling touches on child layer Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, event-listener

I've added a layer as a child in a scene. I want when I touch any sprite on this child layer , touch does not go to parent layer.
I've written following code for register touch events but touches still going to parent layer, instead of returning back from it.

```
void onEnter()
{
    Layer::onEnter();

    // Register Touch Event
    auto dispatcher = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
    auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

    listener->setSwallowTouches(true);

    listener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(onTouchBegan, this);
    listener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(onTouchMoved, this);
    listener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(onTouchEnded, this);

    dispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, _cancelLayer);
}
```

Here _cancelLayer is name of my child layer. Please someone tell what's wrong with this code? I've not register any touch event with parent layer, but when I touch on parent layer, it still go into touch functions.

Note : Size of child layer is much smaller than parent.

In touchBegin I'm doing nothing , I just want to use it for restricting touches to move onto parent layer.

```
bool HeaderTableView::onTouchBegan(Touch *pTouch, Event *pEvent)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TouchEventListener will response to touchs on the whole screen, so you need to check if the touch is in the bounding box you want,like

```
bool HeaderTableView::onTouchBegan(Touch *pTouch, Event *pEvent)
{   
    Vec2 touchLocation = pTouch->getLocation(); // Get the touch position
    touchLocation = _cancelLayer->getParent()->convertToNodeSpace(touchLocation);
    Rect bBox = _cancelLayer->getBoundingBox();
    return bBox.containsPoint(touchLocation);
}
```

Comment: @Nargis it will help if you post the onTouchBegan codes on. if the layer is removed in onTouchBegan, the listener will not swallow touch either

Comment: @Nargis i see, maybe i misunderstood your question, if your problem is that you want the listener handle touch event only when touch in the child layer, i will edit my answer

Comment: Yes exactly , I want that

Comment: I'm going to try that :)